# Microsoft 365 modern search : how to go beyond full text search

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, modern-experience, metadata, refiner

In SharePoint classic, I used to configure a global serach center, with refiners on columns added in pages or documents libraries. Please may you give me information of how to perform this kind of requirements in :

- modern SharePoint pages
- global Microsoft 365 search?

Full text search is really good, but not enough considering metadata.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you look at [PnP Search v4](https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search/) where you can create a custom solution with refiners, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much. We used it on some tenants; we were surprised it was not running with Firefox at all on one tenant. I am surprised (and worried about long term usage) every time a classic functionality is not migrated into the modern experience (whereas metadata can bring better results than text search only...)

Answer (score 0):

**Microsoft Search is the modern search experience in SharePoint in Microsoft 365**.It uses the insights of the Microsoft Graph to show results that are relevant to you. **[Learn more about Microsoft Search for users](https://support.office.com/article/d5ed5d11-9e5d-4f1d-b8b4-3d371fe0cb87)**.
The **classic search experience**, on the other hand, can be tailored more to your organization. **[Learn about the differences between the search experiences](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/differences-classic-modern-search)**.

Both search experiences are turned on by default and as a search administrator you can't turn either search experience off. Which search experience your users see depends on where they search from.

**Classic Search experience**

Users get the classic search experience on publishing sites, classic team sites, and in the Search Center.

**Modern Search experience**

Users get the Microsoft Search experience on the SharePoint start page, hub sites, communication sites, and modern team sites. Learn about classic and modern sites.

If you're in a document library, the search box shows Search this library. If you're in the home page of the site, the box shows Search this site. In all other locations, the search box shows Search.

For more information, please see the **"[Search experiences in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/get-started-with-modern-search-experience)"**.